# Valid provisioning profile not found for this executable

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile

I have my devices registered in my Apple developer account, I have an App ID and I created Provisioning profile that includes all my devices. Now when I try running the project on my iPhone, it gives me this error, "Valid provisioning profile not found for this executable." But when I try on other devices in the provisioning profile, it works!!

All other projects and provisioning profile show similar behaviour to this device. I have confirmed that my device is added and has not been DISABLED on my developer account. What can be the issue?

Comment: bundle id or iOS version may cause issue.

Comment: BundleID is wildcard (*), I also tried using a specific bundle ID. I have iOS version 8.2 and my Deployment target is also 8.2.

Comment: Try resetting your device !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Ronit. This is the solution if your Provisioning profiles are working good to all its containing device but one of it is giving the issue described in the question.

Simply Back-up your device, and reset all settings from your iPhone

Goto iPhone's Settings App -> General -> Reset (Very bottom) -> Reset All Settings.

And later I tried running the App without any changes in my projects and certificates and it works...

Though I would like to highlight it for Apple Engineers... :P

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had an app with explicit app ID and got the same error when using the wildcard profiles, created by Xcode. I could fix it the following way:

1. Point Safari to https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/profile/ and create a development profile with all needed devices
2. Open Xcode's preferences > Accounts
3. Select your Apple ID and click on "View Details…"
4. "Download All"

(This downloads to ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles)

After that I could use Xcode's Run command and get a running app on my device.